# what does mean crond[2113] : (*system*) RELOAD (/etc/cron.d/mycron)

Tags: centos, logs, cron

```
crond[2113] : (*system*) RELOAD (/etc/cron.d/mycron)
```

My cron job is not working and I got the error above in log, What does mean that, how can I know what is going on.

My cron job code:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/
* * * * * root php /var/www/html/app/checkUserAction.php
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not an error. This is the cron daemon informing you that it has detected that `/etc/cron.d/mycron` was modified and loaded the new version of the file.

Errors from the cron daemon itself will be in the same logs (probably, unless you've reconfigured logging). Errors from the job itself are sent as an email to root; check your email.

Comment: thanks...was an php error...I already fixed, how or where can find docs about the cron jobs logs, to know RELOAD, `(*system*)` and that kind of things

Comment: I regret the many times I rebooted to get cron to reload a boot script. `journalctl --follow` clued me into what was happening and your answer here to confirm it.